# How to add unallocated space to partition in this particular case?

Tags: partitioning

How do I resize partition and add unallocated space?

Screenshot of GParted:

[image: That's how my GUI G-Parted looks]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the partition is locked - you can see the little key icon next to the partition name.

The partition is locked because it is mounted. The easiest way around this is to boot from a live USB or CD (a live Ubuntu CD for example). Then you can unmount /dev/sd2 if it happens to be mounted, then you can make the partition size change.

Comment: Does it work with unetbootin?

Comment: Yes it should work as long as the live Linux distro you use has gparted installed (or you can install it if it doesn't). Ubuntu (and other) live CD comes with gparted pre-installed and ready to use.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. When I boot from unetbootin it gives me almost the same problem. The mount point changed from / to /cdrom. If I try to unmount it, it says that it is busy.

Comment: You might be almost there. After you boot from unetbootin, do you have the option to change the device to /dev/sda on the upper right of gparted?

Comment: Also, make sure /dev/sda1 is unmounted (you can right click it to unmount)

Comment: This is what I see from my unetbootin

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/h5xY5Vc

Comment: It looks like /dev/sda2 is mounted. Can you left-click and unmount it? If you can, then the key icon should disappear and you should be able to resize it.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/LPViwIT

Comment: That makes me think that you are still running off of the /dev/sda2 partition. The key is going to be to boot from a live CD or from a USB so that the computer is running FROM that media and not from the hard drive.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to use a USB, it'll take me some time before I come with an answer. Hope everything works. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked! https://i.imgur.com/JgRFo11.png